# password reset feature from laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5

I tried the password reset feature laravel 5.2, however when I tried to submit a password reset, perform an error like this:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EMAIL', table
>   'KSP_ASTRA.dbo.PASSWORD_RESETS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. (SQL: insert into [password_resets] ([email], [token],
>   [created_at]) values (,
>   97fdbc9463ea9807b5da729182960a31293e482ae33b9e42f81b6eee35bd6a4f,
>   2017-08-30 02:24:01.000))

the column email unreadable, even though I didn't change the default display auth password reset laravel.

please, If anyone could help

Comment: please share your view code and your User Model

Comment: Yes, I forgot that the email I use capital letters. Thanks:)